# How do we distinguish someone talking to another person via telepathy rather than via vocal means?

Tags: creative-writing, novel, dialogue

In my sci-fi novel, some people have the ability to talk via telepathy so how do we distinguish telepathy from other types of communication? I would like to do it, because it's not the same, and I want to stress it out.

Anyway, here's an excerpt I wrote just a few moments ago:

> "It won't take too much time. He will be here any moment now." said
>   Tim
>
> "Don't worry the SWAT team is already on their way." Tim told Matthew
>   telepathically.
>
> "Really!? Thank God. I was getting nervous." said Matthew.

Not sure how other people do it, but I would be interested in how this can be done.

Comment: How would you write an inner thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps if you use something else instead of quotation marks for the telepathic dialogue. For example:

`<Don't worry, the SWAT team is already on their way.>`

Parentheses and italics can do the job as well.